# How to "dont select values" in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have application where user inserts name into input box:
My sql query selects name in the database and it works good.
Problem occurs when nothing is inserted. the query selects all database names instead of none.
How do I select nothing if nothing is inserted.

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.BarcodeData
WHERE ModelioPavadinimas LIKE  @ModelioPavadinimas + '%';
```

Comment: `LIKE NULLIF(@ModelioPavadinimas, '') + '%'`. Figuring out why this works is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Presumably you are defining `@ModelioPavadinimas` as `''` not `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, did not think of that.

Comment: Using nullif is nice and compact; of course, the simple logic you need is where column like value *and* value is not blank

Comment: The even more elegant solution is to validate the input in the user interface (and the business logic that runs the query) so that empty values don't get through.

Comment: I guess it all depends on how you think of an empty string. I would personally say that *everything* matches an empty string, but I'm a developer, not a user